# IntelliJ cannot find libraries with gradle or maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use 2 libraries in my SpigotPlugin project. When I include them in my project with Intellij IDEA's library section and import them, everything seems to be fine. When I try to build the project though, it gives me the `package [package] does not exist` error.

What I have tried;

- Invalidate/Restart -> Removes the libraries from the library section in Project Structure
- Cleared `.idea` -> Same issue
- Tried the same thing in Maven -> Same issue

It's not caused by the library since any other library causes the same issue.

I'd appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: Maybe check the package dependence in your Maven, you can check it here https://mvnrepository.com/
You can also post your `pom.xml` that may help.

Comment: My pom.xml does not have anything about these libraries. Does IDEA add them automatically or do I have to add the dependencies myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies must be added in the build script instead (`build.gradle` if you are using Gradle, `pom.xml` if you are using Maven). IntelliJ IDEA will import them automatically.

All the changes you make manually in the module structure will be lost on the next project sync/import with the external build system. You should see a warning in the dialog about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go to Intellij build settings (Ctrl+Alt+S for windows and cmd+alt+S for mac). In maven section check the location of local repository(the .m2 folder). If you copy your external library in the right folder in .m2 directory and add it as a dependency in your pom.xml it will build fine.

Usually Intellij uses bundled maven but I prefer to use my local installation of maven so that I have more control over configs and stuff.